# Error parsing date with grok filter in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I need to parse the date and timestamp in the log to show in `@timestamp` field. I am able to parse timestamp but not date.

Input Log:

```
"2010-08-18","00:01:55","text"
```

My Filter:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => '"(%{DATE})","(%{TIME})","(%{GREEDYDATA:message3})"’}
}
```

Here `DATE` throws `grokparsefailure`.
Also not sure how to update the `@timestamp` field.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `%{DATE}` pattern is not what you want.  It's looking for something in M/D/Y, M-D-Y, D-M-Y, or D/M/Y format.

For a file like this, you could consider using the csv filter:

```
filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["date","time","message3"]
    add_filed => {
       "date_time" => "%{date} %{time}"
    }
  }
  date {
     match => [ "date_time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
     remove_field => ["date", "time", "date_time" ]
  }
}
```

This will handle the case where `message3` has embedded quotes in it that have been escaped.